# Can I use a spreadsheet to calculate profit/loss and current position for trading of shares?

Tags: algorithm, reporting, trading

I have data about some trades of a share (currently only 20 transactions as a learning subset, with the full set covering around 50,000 transactions for different shares).

I'm trying to work out how to determine the profit for each trade, as well as the current position. Not all the held shares are sold in 1 trade, so there is sometimes a carry over (whole and fractional values). Sometimes several buys and sells occur, rather than buy/sell/buy/sell.

I'm NOT the one trading! (Just to make that clear).

I suppose, what I'm trying to get to is "what am I actually asking about?".

I suspect there is a perfectly standardised way of doing this, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Do you have multiple users, or just one?

Comment: It's 5 people's history but I can do 1 at a time (I can filter the data). Once I can understand the sort of algorithm to use, I can (should be able to) implement multiple users.

Comment: [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/forex/12/calculating-profits-and-losses-of-forex-trades.asp) would have more. For the mathematically inclined, there used to be a series on [financial markets using commutative diagrams](https://hoj201.wordpress.com/2016/04/03/finance-explained-in-commutative-diagrams/), but it is 404.